# python lxml: syntax for selectively deleting inline style attributes?

Tags: python, css, html-parsing, lxml, lxml.html

**I'm using python 3.4 with the lxml.html library.**

I'm trying to remove the `border-bottom` in-line styling from html elements that I've targeted with a css selector.

Here's a code fragment showing a sample td element and my selector:

```
html_snippet = lxml.html.fromstring("""<td valign="bottom" colspan="10" align="center" style="background-color:azure; border-bottom:1px solid #000000"><font style="font-family:Times New Roman" size="2">Estimated Future Payouts</font> \n            <br/><font style="font-family:Times New Roman" size="2">Under Non-Equity Incentive</font> \n            <br/><font style="font-family:Times New Roman" size="2">Plan Awards</font> \n        </td>""")
selection = html_snippet.cssselect('td[style*="border-bottom"]')
selection.attrib['style']
>>>>'background-color: azure;border-bottom:1px solid #000000'
```

What's the proper way to access the in-line style properties so I can remove the `border-bottom` attribute from any element I target with my selector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approach it by splitting the `style` attribute value by `;`, create a CSS property name -> value map, remove the `border-bottom` from the map and reconstruct the `style` attribute again by joining the elements of the map with `;`. Sample implementation:

```
style = selection.attrib['style']
properties = dict([item.split(":") for item in style.split("; ")])

del properties['border-bottom']

selection.attrib['style'] = "; ".join([key + ":" + value for key, value in properties.items()])

print(lxml.html.tostring(selection))
```

I'm pretty sure you can break this solution easily.

---

Alternatively, here is a rather "crazy" option - dump the data into the "html" file, open the file in a browser via [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html), remove the attribute via javascript and print out the HTML representation of the element after:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver   

data = """
<td valign="bottom" colspan="10" align="center" style="background-color:azure; border-bottom:1px solid #000000"><font style="font-family:Times New Roman" size="2">Estimated Future Payouts</font> \n            <br/><font style="font-family:Times New Roman" size="2">Under Non-Equity Incentive</font> \n            <br/><font style="font-family:Times New Roman" size="2">Plan Awards</font> \n        </td>
"""
with open("index.html", "w") as f:
    f.write("<body><table><tr>%s</tr></table></body>" % data)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("file://" + os.path.abspath("index.html"))

td = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("td")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style['border-bottom'] = '';", td)

print(td.get_attribute("outerHTML"))

driver.close()
```

Prints:

```
<td valign="bottom" colspan="10" align="center" style="background-color: rgb(240, 255, 255);"><font
        style="font-family:Times New Roman" size="2">Estimated Future Payouts</font>
    <br><font style="font-family:Times New Roman" size="2">Under Non-Equity Incentive</font>
    <br><font style="font-family:Times New Roman" size="2">Plan Awards</font>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks!  For others, note the dict items method in alecxe's first answer is the python 2 .iteritems rather than the python 3 .items

Comment: @deseosuho oops, yeah, fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a package for that, although overkill in this case.

```
import cssutils
sheet = cssutils.parseStyle('background-color: azure;border-bottom:1px solid #000000')
sheet.removeProperty('border-bottom')  # returns '1px solid #000'
print(sheet.cssText)
```

Outputs `background-color: azure`

Comment: Nice find! I think this is an easiest option here at the moment.